# How do I make it so that when someone refreshes the page, the textbox still has the value in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

In JQuery, is this possible? Is there a plugin for this (that handles cookies, etc...)

Comment: will b done with session variables, but it's not good idea? what u exact want?

Comment: For example...when you are filling out a stackoverflow question but "refresh" the page, the question will still be there. I just want a simple Jquery plugin that can persist values automatically.

Comment: a textfield will hold its value on refresh if its value specified in the html markup , or loaded at page load ( read from a cookie , session etc .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

is maybe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Either store the text in a cookie or in a server-sided session.
Cookies are usually limited to a maximum size.